# How to add a child page to a Custom Post Type "Post"

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

Friends, Hello.

I have an issue, i'm searching for an answer for 2 days now. I think I have checked all the 10 firsts google pages of 20 different requests by now.
So, this is it.

I have a custom post type named "Footballer".
I have created 2 "Posts" of that CPT, which are "Messi" and "Ronaldo".
My permalinks for these 2 footballers are "mysite.com/footballer/messi/" and "mysite.com/footballer/ronaldo/". It is OK for me.

Now, I want to add a child page "about" (or "stats", or anything) to my footballers and I want this page to be available by the link "mysite.com/footballer/messi/about" (just add the child page slug after the cpt post link).
Obviously, I want to create a single page "about", not one for every footballer I have, and in this page I would retrieve data for the specific footballer (by functions/shortcodes).

Nota: the cpt and values in this post are fictionnals, I know I would display the about/stats directly in the footballer cpt post. I am just trying to explain what I need -> a generic child page for a cpt, available by "mysite.com/cpt/cptpost/childpage".

How can I do it ? I s it even possible ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT ;**

As it is not possible with Divi, can I try to rewrite the URL of my subpage ? If my subpage url is "mysite/subpage/?foot=messi", can I make it appear "mysite/footballer/messi/subpage".

I tried this code, without success

```
function my_rewrite_url() {

    add_rewrite_tag( '%foot%','([^&]+)' );
    
    add_rewrite_rule(
      'footballer/([^/]+)/subpage',
      'index.php?pagename=subpage&foot=$matches[1]',
      'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_url' );
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How did you create your Custom Post Type? There is an argument `'hierarchical'`. That needs to be set to TRUE `'hierarchical'  => TRUE,`. You may also want to set the `capability_type` to `page`, `'capability_type'     => 'page'`

Comment: Hi disinfor. I created my Custom Post Type with the plugin CPTUI. The parameter "hierarchical' is on true. Where do I find the 'capability_type' in the UI ? Or this parameter is not available and I have do redesign the CPT by code ? Once it's done, where do I specifify that child page ? Thx for helping

Comment: Does that plugin have a section for the "supports" parameters? If so, you can add `page-attributes` that will allow you to select a parent page.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that page-attrributes. I can select a parant page but my issue is I did not create a page for my CPT footballer. I use the theme DIVI and I have created a template wich is applied for all the footballers. I don't have a page for footballer in my "Pages" section in Wordpress so I can't put it as parent page

Comment: You should have mentioned in your question you are using Divi and you created a Divi template. You won't be able to do what you want with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for custom taxonomies on the custom post type.